# Why does PHPUnit "receives" an Error object instead of an Exception object

Tags: php, phpunit

When I test a constructor that throws an exception using expectExceptionMessage('exception message') the test fails and the actual message text is prefixed with "Class 'namespace\Class_Name'".

It also states that an exception of type Error was thrown instead of type Exception as expected.

Am I throwing my exception incorrectly?

I was able to make the test pass by leaving out the expectExceptionMessage function and enclosing the code in a try catch statement.
Which doesn't make sense to me.

Using the annotations

```
/**
     * @expectedException        Exception
     * @expectedExceptionMessage no_file.json not found
     */
```

Also didn't solve the problem.

PHPUnit test code:

```
public function testNonExistingFileInConstructor() {
        $this->expectException( 'Exception' );
        $this->expectExceptionMessage( 'no_file.json not found');
        new Json_File('no_file.json');
    }
```

Code throwing the exception:

```
public function __construct( $path_to_file ) {
        $json_file = file_get_contents( $path_to_file );
        if( false === $json_file ) {
            throw new Exception( $json_file . ' not found', 500 );
        }

        $data = json_decode( $json_file, true );
        if ( is_null( $data) ) {
            throw new Exception( 'invalid json in ' . $json_file, 600 );
        }

        $this->data = $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Do not use annotations](https://thephp.cc/news/2019/02/help-my-tests-stopped-working#expecting-exceptions) to expect exceptions.

Always use fully qualified class names with `expectException()`, for instance `$this->expectException(YourNamespace\Exception::class);` instead of `$this->expectException('Exception');`. 'Exception' is just a string that cannot be resolved to the correct, fully qualified name of the exception you're expecting.

Comment: I did see that in your article on why not to use annotations, I just tried to see if it would work :)

I just tested it and ofc (since we owe PHPUnit to you) it works!
Thanks!

Just for my understanding, I see that $this->expectExceptionMessage('my message') now also works after fixing the $this->expectException call.

Does this mean that the expectExceptionMessage function is dependant on the correct class being passed to expectException?

Thanks again, not just for the answer but the speed as well :)